# Xuggle on Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, xuggle

Is it possible to use Xuggle for Blackberry development?

Has anyone attempted this?

Thank you.

Comment: Does it support J2ME ? If no, then it's not supported on BlackBerry.

Comment: I have a feeling its not supported, just checking.  Any alternatives?

Comment: I don't know, what it your need? And what does this LIB do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xuggle uses [native code](http://wiki.xuggle.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Why_do_I_need_to_install_a_DLL_or_Shared_Library_for_a_Java_application.3F) and relies on the FFmpeg library - neither of which are supported by J2ME or Blackberry.

Comment: Help me with Xuggler: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010557/beginners-guide-to-working-with-xuggler