# Beginner's Guide to Setup Xuggler

Tags: eclipse, maven, jar, pom.xml, xuggler

To work with Xuggler you need `xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar`. According to the people who made this, most users only need the above-mentioned JAR file. However, this is what they say about using Xuggler **without** Maven or Ivy:

> ### Using Xuggler WITHOUT Apache Maven or Apache Ivy
>
> What are you... stuck
>   in 2003? Anyway, if you insist on this, Xuggler's pre-compiled
>   binaries (including native versions) can be [found here](http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/xuggle/xuggle-xuggler/). Make sure that
>   xuggle-xuggler.jar and its dependencies are included in your Java
>   classpath. See the **xuggle-xugger-*.pom** file distributed with the
>   version of Xuggler that you use to find the (small) set of dependent
>   jars, and download them as well.

I downloaded the `xuggle-xuggler.jar` file for the latest version, 5.4 but I don't understand the pom file for it.

What **dependencies** is he talking about?

Next, how do I download these **dependencies** ?

Once I get these dependencies, how do I start working in Eclipse?

---

---

### Update After Downloading Dependencies

I have the following directory structure:
[image]

`xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar` is stored in **E:\xuggle**

[image]

the various `xuggler dependencies` are stored in **E:\xuggle\xuggle-dependencies**

### Question:

How do I start working with Xuggler in Eclipse? What paths do I have to set and what values do these paths have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following files list the other jars which xuggle depends upon:

- [ivy.xml](http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/xuggle/xuggle-xuggler/5.4/ivy-5.4.xml)
- [pom.xml](http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/xuggle/xuggle-xuggler/5.4/xuggle-xuggler-5.4.pom)

You can read these and then manually retrieve them from the appropriate repository, but I would submit it's simpler to start using a dependency manager.

You asked how to download these dependencies, well ivy has a convenient [command-line](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/standalone.html) mode of operation. (See example below)

Eclipse integration is very tough.... Once you've downloaded the jar you could try and generate the ".classpath" file or just manually add each jar via the Eclipse GUI.
The reason I don't recommend this approach is because there are Eclipse plugins for both Maven and Ivy that would do this for you automatically.

## Example

Run ivy from command-line as follows:

```
java -jar ivy.jar -settings ivysettings.xml -dependency xuggle xuggle-xuggler 5.4 -retrieve "lib/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"
```

It will retrieve xuggle and all its dependencies into a "lib" directory as follows:

```
├── ivysettings.xml
└── lib
    ├── commons-cli-1.1.jar
    ├── logback-classic-1.0.0.jar
    ├── logback-core-1.0.0.jar
    ├── slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar
    └── xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar
```

### ivysettings.xml

This file tells ivy to retrieve jars from either [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/), or the Maven repository provided by the Xuggle project.

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="repos" />
    <resolvers>
        <chain name="repos">
            <ibiblio name="central" m2compatible="true"/>
            <ibiblio name="xuggle" m2compatible="true" root="http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java"/>
        </chain>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

Comment: Mr. O'Connor I downloaded all the dependencies. I edited the question. Now can you please tell me how I can do it manually????

Comment: and I have to set the classpath to what? **E:\xuggler** or what? :)

Comment: Assuming you're in the Java perspective, right-click on the Project and select "Properties". This will launch a new window, select "Java Build Path" and then added the jars via the "Libraries" tab. There's a "Add external Jars" button..... Is this your first time using Eclipse?

Answer (score 3):

Don't fight Maven, embrace it. These days all major build systems are maven compatible (Maven, Ivy, Gradle, Grape, Buildr ...). But you can use Maven from Eclipse:

create a file called pom.xml with this content:

```
<project>
 <groupId>com.foo<groupId>      <!-- change these -->
 <artifactId>foo</artifactId>   <!-- parameters to whatever -->
 <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version><!-- you like -->
 <repositories>
  <repository>
   <id>xuggle repo</id>
   <url>http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/</url>
  </repository>
 </repositories>
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>xuggle</groupId>
   <artifactId>xuggle-xuggler</artifactId>
   <version>5.2</version>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>
</project>
```

Install the [m2e](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) extension and, from Eclipse, do `"File > Import ... > Existing Maven Projects"`. In the dialog, select the Folder that contains the pom.xml.

Make sure that the Folder's layout is like this:

```
pom.xml
src/main/java // sources go here
src/test/java // test sources go here
```

Then you should have a working Eclipse project with the required dependencies.

---

Update after your update:

You can see the dependencies when you look at this file: http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/xuggle/xuggle-xuggler/5.2/xuggle-xuggler-5.2.pom

- commons-cli (a utility library for command line processing)
- logback (a logging framework)
- junit (a testingframework)

Maven will take care of loading these dependencies for you. So will Eclipse, if you use the m2e plugin as suggested above.

---

If you absolutely don't want to do that, you will have to download the dependencies manually. Look at the pom file above, note the names and versions of the dependencies, look them up at http://mvnrepository.com/ and download them there, e.g. this is the page for slf4j-api: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.4

Comment: I downloaded all the dependencies with proper version numbers. Now how do I get it into Eclipse? I know I will have to set some paths. But what paths? **Note:** Some are .zip files and others are jar directly. **Whats the next step?**