# How do i install xuggler dependencies on linux?

Tags: java, linux, maven, dependencies, xuggler

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Beginner’s Guide to Setup Xuggler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010557/beginners-guide-to-setup-xuggler)

I downloaded xuggler-xuggler-5.4.jar which I've successfully added to netbeans. The problem is getting it work since it has so many dependencies. I looked in the .jar file and didn't see any pom file so I googled the file. Now I have the .pom file and have to use Maven to download the dependencies. Maven so utterly confuses me, so I was hoping that someone could just give me the command line to get the dependencies.

Comment: Maven is not your only option, eg: Gradle, ant+vy. Whatever you choose the key point is you require something that performs dependency management.