# Beginner's Guide to Setup Xuggler__Help

Tags: ivy, xuggler

I've found the "Beginner's Guide to Setup Xuggler" article from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010557/beginners-guide-to-setup-xuggler). I was trying to follow the best chosen answer. While going through the steps, I got stuck @ "Run ivy from command-line as follows:" I didn't had Ivy at first, so I headed to [Ivy's download page](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/download.cgi), and downloaded from the [Snapshot Build](http://builds.apache.org/view/A-F/view/Ant/job/Ivy) section of the site. Then, I tested with both jar files, but while running the command stated in the Beginner's Guide, I'm getting this message: "ivy configuration file not found: ivysettings.xml". So, what did I do wrong, need I follow the "Building from source" section from the site? If so, can you please give me a detailed description of how to do it, I'm kinda new in these things. Long story short, I need to know how o get a legit "ivy.jar" file as stated in the command line of the Guide.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Beginner's Guide to Setup Xuggler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010557/beginners-guide-to-setup-xuggler)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I've solved the problem my own way, kind of. So, I'm gonna share it here so that other fellows like me may profit from it. So, what I did was that I (obviously) downloaded Xuggler 5.4. Then, I downloaded its dependencies manually as listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010557/beginners-guide-to-setup-xuggler). Then, on my IDE, I just had to import Xuggler and all of its dependencies which I previously downloaded and BAM, it worked like a charm. So, if any of you are having problem finding those dependencies or have any queries concerning this "unofficial" method of mine, you can contact me via email. I'll gladly help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know from Xuggler, but... the error message said you're missing ivysettings.xml.  The message is probably from ivy.jar, so you definitely have that.  ivysettings.xml is a required Ivy config file that tells what repositories you want to pull jars from.  There may be a default one in the Xuggler distro, but probably not.  You need to look at the ivy documentation to get farther.  Or, use Maven instead.  While I'm not a fan of Maven, for this kind of situation it may be easier.

Comment: @SHA33, you might want to post your comment as an answer.  It's not considered "bad form" at all.